# JQuery upload file for Mailgun attachment

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload, mailgun

I need to attach some files to an email using Mailgun.
Actually Im sending all data (from, to, subject ...) to php script via ajax.
For uploading file, Im using JQuery.fileupload.js, that upload files to server and give me back name and url if it.

Here a simple of Mailgun request:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
'from'    => 'Excited User <cm.carlo.martini@gmail.com>',
'to'      => 'foo@example.com',
'cc'      => 'baz@example.com',
'bcc'     => 'bar@example.com',
'subject' => 'Hello',
'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
'html'    => '<html>HTML version of the body</html>'), array(
'attachment' => array('@/path/to/file.txt', '@/path/to/file.txt')));
```

I tried to add path to files to "attachment" array but doesnt work.
How do I send those files using their urls?
Probably because of 'multipart/form-data'...